# Download file with Angular and Django

Tags: angularjs, service, download, factory

I have a table containing a list of files fetched from the server. I also have a button, that downloads the selected file. So I made a function which call a service and it opens the response (the file) in a new window, so the user can download it.
Controller:

```
  $scope.download = function() {

if ($scope.cancelPromise) {
  $scope.cancelPromise.resolve();
}
$scope.cancelPromise = $q.defer();
UserFileSrv.downloadFile.download(
  {
    fileId: $scope.selectedFile.id
  },function(data) {
    if (data) {
      toaster.pop('success', 'Success', 'success');
      window.open(data);
    }
  }, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      toaster.pop('error', 'Error', error);
    }
  }
);
```

};

The service:

```
angular.module('app').factory('UserFileSrv', ['$resource', function($resource) {
var userFile = {
    downloadFile: $resource('my_url/:fileId/?', {
      fileId: '@fileId'
    }, {
      download: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: false
      }
    })
    };
    return userFile;
}]);
```

The browser shows the 'success' toaster, but it opens a window which contains this string: `Cannot GET /%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

Note: the Content-Type of the response is: `application/json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you try to pass the downloaded content to the window.open function.
window.open accept the url as the first argument.
You can solve your problem in two cases:

1) Form the url to the resource (ex: 'my_url/12343') and pass it to the window open. But make sure that your server returns your response with header **Content-Disposition=attachment;fileName=someFileName**. It will force the browser to process the response as an attachment.

2)Otherwise you can use Blob. (it won't work in IE 9 or less)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Instead of windows.open you can make the following:

```
function downloadBlob(fileName, blob){

  //IE case
  if (!!window.navigator.msSaveBlob){
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    return;
  }

  //create url
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  //create invisible acnhor, to specify the file name
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style = "display: none";
  a.href = url;
  a.download = fileName;
  a.click();

  setTimeout(function(){
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }, 100);

}

var data = {x: 1, y:2, name: 'abc'};
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {type : 'octet/stream'});

downloadBlob('myData.json', blob)
```

The full solution which shows how to download blobs with ngResource is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dvladir/dzc180fg/10/)

Comment: I'm trying the second way and it seems work, but it download the file 'myData.json'... What can I do if the file that I'm dowloading is an image? I will dont know the format of the file, it could be everything

Comment: You mention that your response is application/json. But if you are going to download different file types, the response's content-type should also differ. You can analize it and choose the proper extension.

Comment: I'm doing front-end side. The person who is doing the back-end side, told me that the response of the download calling is 'Content-Type: application/json'... but the file could be a png, a pdf, etc

Comment: Whe you retreive the file list from the server, do you have the file's names with it's extensions?

Comment: Uhm wait, in the 'Network' in chrome I see that the Response Headers has this content-type:  Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=21.png
Content-Type:application/force-download

Comment: p.s. yes I have all the name

Comment: Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898265/get-response-header-in-then-function-of-a-ngresource-objects-promise-propert). There is an example how, the response headers can be retrived with $resource service.

Comment: Have I to add     return Rating.get({id: newId}).$promise;     into function(data) {    if (data) { ......  ?

Comment: Find an aswer with interceptor. I think you should add something like this. Add intersceptor to your UserFileSrv. So as a result it should wrap in the response headers and data in one object.

Comment: Take a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvladir/dzc180fg/10/). I hope it will help. To make it work in your case you shuold change the resource url and add some logic to extract/determine the file name.

Comment: It could be the right way! It alert 'success' but it shows this in the console: Error: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 2-argument overloads of URL.createObjectURL.

Comment: I've tested it in Chrome 50.0.2661.94 m, Firefox 45.0.2 and IE 11. And everything works ok. What browser do you use and what type of file you try to download?

Comment: LOL I forgot to write ' responseType: 'blob', now it works... thank you very very much, also +1 useful too!!

Comment: I was glad to help